# Optional Sampling Theorem in discrete setting

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

I have a question about proving the optional sampling theorem in discrete setting. I dont know if what I am doing is mathematical justified. Can someone help me with this?

Defenition: Let $\tau$ be a stopping time, then $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}=\{F\subset \Omega: \forall n \in N \cup \{\infty \}, F\cap(\tau\leq n)\in \mathcal{F}_{n} \}$ is a sigma-algebra.

Defenition: Let $[M_{k}, k \in \mathcal{N}]$ be a martingale w.r.t. a filtration. Let $\tau$ be a stopping time that is never $\infty.$ Then $M_{\tau}$ is a function defined by $\forall \omega \in \Omega: M_{\tau}(\omega)=M_{\tau(\omega)}(\omega)$

Defenition Indicator function: Let $F\in \mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma algebra. Then the indicator function is a function from $\Omega$ to $[0,1]$. $1_{F}(\omega)=1$ if $\omega \in F$, else $1_{F}(\omega)=0$

Question 1) Prove that $M_{\tau}(\omega)\in m\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$

Question 2) When in addition is given that $\tau \leq K$, where $K$ is a given positive integer, prove then that $E(M_{\tau})=M_{0}$. Here it might help to write $1_{\Omega}=\sum_{k=0}^{K}1_{\tau=k}$.

---

**My attempts** to answer these questions.

(Q1)
Since $\tau(\omega) \neq \infty, \forall \omega \in \Omega$, we can write for some $t \in N$

$M_{\tau}=\sum_{i=0}^{t}1_{\tau=i}M_{i} \in \mathcal{F}_{t}$, Since the indicator and the martingale are both random variables, and products of random variables are also random variables.

Then $\forall n \in N: [\sum_{i=0}^{n}1_{\tau=i}M_{i}]^{-1}(B(\Re))\cap(\tau \leq n) \in \mathcal{F}_{n}$. Since both parts of the intersections are in $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ and hence $M_{\tau}(\omega)\in m\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$

(Q2)
$E(M_{\tau})=E(M_{\tau}1_{\Omega})=E(M_{\tau}\sum_{k=0}^{K}1_{\tau=k})=\sum_{k=0}^{K}E(M_{k}1_{\tau=k})=\sum_{k=0}^{K}E(M_{k}1_{\tau=k}|\mathcal{F}_{0})=\sum_{k=0}^{K}M_{0}E(1_{\tau=k})=\sum_{k=0}^{K}M_{0}P(1_{\tau=k})=M_{0}$

Can someone assure me whether my attempts are legit? Or give legit proofs?

---

I have a new attempt to answer question 1. I think this one is more general.

Given is that $M:\Omega \times \mathcal{T} \rightarrow \Re$ such that $M(n,\cdot) \in m \mathcal{F}_{n}, \forall n \in \mathcal{N}$

$\tau: \Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{N}$

$\mathcal{F}_{\tau}=\{ F \subset \Omega: \forall n \in \mathcal{N} \cup\{ \infty \}, F \cap (\tau \leq n) \in \mathcal{F}_{n} \}$

Claim: $M_{\tau} \in m \mathcal{F}_{\tau}$

Proof:

$M_{\tau}(\omega)=M(\tau(\omega),\omega) \forall \omega \in \Omega$.

Since $M(n,\cdot) \in m \mathcal{F}_{n}, M_{n}^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\Re))\subseteq \mathcal{F}_{n}$ and $\forall \omega \in \Omega: \tau(\omega) \in \mathcal{N}$
it follows that

$M_{\tau(\omega)}^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\Re)) \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{\tau(\omega)}$

$\rightarrow M_{\tau(\omega)}^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau(\omega)}, \forall B \in \mathcal{B}(\Re)$

$\rightarrow M_{\tau(\omega)}^{-1}(B) \cap (\tau \leq n) \in \mathcal{F}_{n}, \forall B \in \mathcal{B}(\Re)$

$\rightarrow M_{\tau}^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau}, \forall B \in \mathcal{B}(\Re)$

$\rightarrow M_{\tau} \in m \mathcal{F}_{\tau}$.

Hence $M_{\tau}$ is a random variable on $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$.

Comment: (Q1) What you do works when $\tau$ is *bounded*. You only know that $\tau$ is *almost surely finite*, which is more general. (Q2) Apply the answer to your other question.

Comment: @Did 
(Q1) Do you maybe know how to prove this then in the general case? 
(Q2) I think I did use here that $M_{\tau} \in m\digamma_{\tau}$? So what do you exactly mean?

Comment: What is mF? If you are referring to the boundedness of $M_\tau$, no this is not necessary.

Comment: I mean that $M_{\tau}$ is measurable in $\mathcal{F}$

Comment: @Did In question 1 I want to prove that $M_{\tau}$ is a random variable w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$. This is equivalent to the statement that $M_{\tau} \in m\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$ right?

Comment: I see: "[your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/430026/6179)".

Comment: @Did, I don't understand exactly what you mean with my other question? I have still problems with the questions 1 and 2 stated above. With question 1: (as you said yourself) that I proved that $M_{\tau}(\omega) \in m \mathcal{F}$ when $\tau$ is boundend. But not yet for the case when $\tau$ is almost surely finite (which is more general). I don't know how I can prove this, so if you could help me there?

Comment: @Did, Secondly, is my answer of question 2 corrrect? I really hope you will help me? I'm really lost right now.

Comment: To prove the measurability of $M_\tau$, you might want to express it as the pointwise limit of the random variables $M_{\tau\wedge n}$.

Comment: @Did, I did another attempt to prove that $M_{\tau}$ is a random variable on $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$. Would you have a look at it? I think this might be right!

Comment: Seems quite dubious. I would be myself in great trouble if I had to explain the inclusion where $\mathcal F_{\tau(\omega)}$ first appears.

Comment: @Did, I thought, $\forall \omega \in \Omega, \tau(\omega) \in \mathcal{N}$. So it should hold right?

Comment: $M_{\tau(\omega)}^{-1}(B)=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid M_{\tau(\omega)}(\omega)\in B\}$??? The horror, the horror...

Comment: Yes, your defenition of the inverse of $M$ is right I think.

Comment: For the last time (since I already tried to say this several times), manipulating things like $\mathcal F_{\tau(\omega)}$ and $M_{\tau(\omega)}^{-1}(B)$ leads to chaos. To be quite explicit the event in the RHS of my last comment is $M_\tau^{-1}(B)$, not what you think it is...

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: I just saw your updated answer for question (1), and it is essentially the same as the one I have written here. Maybe the alternate presentation will be useful anyways.

**Question 1**:

So, an equivalent definition for $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$ is:
$$ \mathcal{F}_{\tau} = \{ F \subset \Omega: F \cap \{\tau = n\} \in \mathcal{F}_n, \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}\} $$

To show that $M_{\tau}$ is adapted to $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$, we need to show that for an arbitrary Borel set $B$, the event $\{M_{\tau} \in B\}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$-measurable. By the definition of $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$, this is equivalent to showing that:
$$ \{M_n \in B\} \cap \{\tau = n\} \in \mathcal{F}_n $$
$\{M_n\}$ is a martingale, so $\{M_n \in B\} \in \mathcal{F}_n$. Also, $\tau$ is a stopping time so $\{\tau = n\} \in \mathcal{F}_n$ also. Thus their intersection is also $\in \mathcal{F}_n$.

**Question 2**:

OK, I'm not sure about the hints you've given, but here is one easy method. I'm also assuming that $\mathcal{F}_0 = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ but you can correct me if I'm wrong. If it's wrong then... I'm pretty sure there's some information still missing about the problem.

Denote the process stopped at time $n$ by $M_{\tau \wedge n}$. As Did mentioned in the comments, you have [previously shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430026/proof-that-a-stopped-martingale-is-a-martingale) that $\{M_{\tau \wedge n}\}$ is a martingale. You can verify that $E M_{\tau \wedge n} = M_0$ for all $n$. Then since $\tau \leq K$, setting $n = K$ gives the result.

Comment: First of all, thanx for the alternative for Q1, it's nice. Secondly, I thought I could do that, since we have a filtration, and I apply the tower property and $M$ is a martingale. Then again, maybe I can't do this since we do not take the expectation of $M$ only, but from M times the indicator function. So, that is the part of the proof I doubted myself the most too! Maybe you know how to avoid this, or an other proof?

Comment: By the way, my teacher gave the following hint (which we should prove if we use it)

$EM_{k}1_{\tau =k} =^{?} EM_{K}1_{\tau =k}$ and $E(M_{K}|\mathcal{F}_{k}=M_{k}$) by defenition of a martingale

Comment: Can you be a little more careful in your notation? I think you made a a typo. Your last assertion is not obvious to me. Also, are you sure you're not trying to prove that $E(M_{\tau}) = E(M_0)$?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. We (I) need to prove that $E(M_{\tau})=M_{0}$. The hint that my teacher gave is not obvious to me neither, however he told us that we could use that.

Comment: Do we know anything about $\mathcal{F}_0$? I'm guessing that it's defined here to be $\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$, but you never explicitly stated it. That would also imply that $M_0$ is constant, so $E M_0 = M_0$.

Comment: It is not explicit given that we assume that $\mathcal{F}=\{\Omega, \Phi \}$, but in the lectures we got we normally assumed that that was the case. So I think it is a legit assumption  we can take here. Thanks for your efforts!