# Verification of the hypotheses and application of Doobs' optional stopping theorem to 2D simple symmetric random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk

In the following problem there are a few things about the application of Doobs's optional stopping theorem (DOST)that I am not sure about. It would be great if you guys could clear this up. Below the statement of the theorem that I am using

[image]

**Observation**: Note that the conditions of the DOST theorem only need to be checked for the stopped process

Let $M_n=D_n^2-n$ I have already proven that it is a martingale. My question is about (b). I now I have to apply DOST to it,so this is what I did. I want to apply the theorem -case iii)- I have to verify that  $M_n$ is of bounded increments and that $E[T]<\infty$. Following the hint, I do it for the stopped process: $M_n^{\nu_r}:=M_{n\land \nu_r }$, provided that $\nu_r$ is a stopping time:

**$M_n^{\nu_r}$ is of bounded increments:**

$|M_{n+1}^{\nu_r}-M_n^{\nu_r}|=| (D_{n+1}^{\nu_r})^2-(n+1)-(D_n^{\nu_r})^2-n |=|(D_{n+1}^{\nu_r})^2-1-(D_n^{\nu_r})^2|\le |(D_{n+1}^{\nu_r})^2-(D_n^{\nu_r})^2| +1 $

On the other hand $D_{n+1}^2=|| S_{n+1}||^2=|| S_n+X_{n+1}||^2=||S_n||^2+||X_{n+1}||^2+2S_n\cdot X_{n+1} =D_n^2 + 1 +2S_n\cdot X_{n+1}\le D_n^2 + 1 +2||S_n|| ||X_{n+1}||=D_n^2 + 1+2D_n$

so at $n=\nu_r: $

$$D_{\nu_r+1}^2-D_{\nu_r}^2\le 1+2 D_{\nu_r}\le 1+2(r+1)=2r+3 $$

where in the last step I have used that

$$r+1 \ge D_{\nu_r} > r \tag {*}$$

because I only move in steps of 1 unit and at the stopped time I can't be more that 1 unit away from the threshold distance.

**$E[\nu_r]<\infty$ :**  No idea

Using DOST ( case iii ), I get that

$$E[D_{\nu_r}^2-\nu_r]=E[M_{\nu_r}]=E[M_0]=E[D_0^2]$$

, but I don't how to compute this , but I know it has to be $0$ so that I can have
$E[D_{\nu_r}^2]=E[\nu_r]$

which I use in (*):

$$r+1 \ge D_{\nu_r} > r$$
$$(r+1)^2 \ge D_{\nu_r}^2  > r^2$$
$$(r+1)^2 \ge E[D_{\nu_r}^2]=E[\nu_r] > r^2$$
$$(r+1)^2/r^2 \ge r^{-2}E[\nu_r] > 1$$
$$\lim_{r\to \infty}r^{-2}E[\nu_r] =1$$

**My questions are**

1. Why is the observation true ? what difference does it make to verify the hypothesis for the whole processes rather that for stopped process? The theorem says I have to verify it for the whole process, so I wonder where this remark comes from
2. How do I check that $\nu_r$ is a stopping time? According to my definition, I have to prove that $\{\nu_r \le n\} \in \mathcal F_n$ , where $\mathcal F_n$ is the natural filtration of the walk:  $\mathcal F_n=\sigma(S_0,S_1,S_2,...S_n)$ and how do I prove that $E[\nu_r]=E[\inf\{n: D_n >r \}]<\infty$ ?  I have no idea on how to compute the expectation of something with $\inf$
3. In the application of the theorem: Why would $E[D_0^2]=0 $ be true ?

---

The theorem I am using

[image]

[image]

Comment: For (i), it's an elementary fact that stopped processes are sub/super martingales. You can look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430026/proof-that-a-stopped-martingale-is-a-martingale for details. 

(ii) The event $\nu_r \leq n$ is $\cup_{j=1}^n \{|X_j|^2 > r\}$ which is a union of events in $\mathcal{F}_n$. 

To show the expected value of $\nu_r$ is finite, try looking at the event that in $2r$ moves, our random walk moves $r$ steps to the right. 

(iii) S_0 starts at the origin, so $D_0$ is the distance from $S_0$ and the origin, i.e., 0. $D_0^2 - 0 = 0-0.$

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed About i), I know that stopped processes are martingales,, but I am not sure why the condition of the theorem don't have to be verified for the whole process when the hypothesis of the theorem clearly ask to do that

Comment: @some_math_guy since $\tau\wedge n$ is a bounded stopping time, OST can be used immediately. The rest can follow with convergence theorems. This is just a standard procedure, not a necessary one.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed Could you give more details about how your claims in ii)? I have no idea why that union would be equal to the event I need, Secondly, why do I need to look at that particular event you are mentioning to determine that $\nu_r \le \infty$? To find the expectation I would have to know the probabilities of all possible $\nu_r$ and sum the values of each one times its probability

Comment: The random walker could stay inside the ball of radious r forever so the possibilities seem to be infinite

Comment: I can't really elaborate on the union, but the gist is that to determine if $\{\nu_r \leq n\} \in \mathcal{F}_n$, we only need to look at the values of our random walk at times 1,2,...,n and check if they are a certain distance from the origin. Intuitively, these events are in $\mathcal{F}_1, \mathcal{F}_2,...,\mathcal{F}_n.$ 

The random walk we are looking at a markov chain and in fact strong markov. The event $A$ that in $2r$ steps our random walk goes $2r$ steps to the right has a positive probability, and the event that $\nu_r > 2rn$ is contained in $A^C$ occurring $2r$ times.

Comment: I can make an answer if you want, but the idea is that $\nu_r$ can be bounded above by a geometric random variable.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed Yes please more details would be appreciated, I've been all day on this and I don't quite your argument about the finite expectation. To start with yo say  the event has positive probability: I mean yeah sure, we are dealing with discrete events, any possibility would have a non zero probability I guess, what is so useful about this one? besides what about any other possible event that for sure has a non zero probabilty: the expectation could be larger and larger. I don't get  the A^c argument either. I have no knowledge of Markov chains by the way

Answer (score 1):

This is only addressing the claim that $\mathbb{E}[\nu_r]$ is finite. We first use the following identity for nonnegative integer random variables
$$\mathbb{E}_0[\nu_r] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}_0(\nu_r \geq n).$$
In this case the subscript 0 means the random walk started at the origin.
Our goal is to bound the probabilities on the right hand side.

Pick $M = 2r$. Consider the event $A$ where the random walk starts at $x_0 \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ and $\nu_r$ is defined as the time it takes to get euclidean distance $r$ away from the origin, the random walk goes to the right $M$ times, i.e., $S_0 = x_0, S_1 = x_0 + (1,0), ... S_M = x_0 + (M,0).$ Note that $\mathbb{P}_{x_0}(A) > 0$, so in particular, the probability of $A_{}^C$, (the event that $A_{}$ does not occur) is less than 1.

It follows that $$\mathbb{P}_{x_0}(\nu_r \geq M) \leq \mathbb{P}_{x_0}(A_{}^C)$$
because $A_{} \subset \{\nu_r < M\}$.

Relabel the expectation as follows and use the following bound:
$$\mathbb{E}_0[\nu_r] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^M \mathbb{P}_0(\nu_r \geq nM+m) \leq 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^M \mathbb{P}_0(\nu_r \geq nM).$$

We are basically done: if $\nu_r \geq nM$, it means that event $A$ did not occur $n$ times. (We are throwing some conditioning under the rug where we are conditioning on the value of $S_M,S_{2M},S_{3M},..,S_{(n-1)M}$ and using that increments of the markov chain are independent, and that $A$ doesn't depend on the initial value of the chain.) This leads to the bound
$$\mathbb{P}(\nu_r \geq nM) \leq \mathbb{P}(A^C)^n.$$

Now use the sum of a geometric series to conclude that since $\mathbb{P}(A^C) < 1$, $\mathbb{E}[\nu_r]$ is finite.

To elaborate on the conditioning (you should do this for yourself,) let $B_r$ be the set of points in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ that are less than $r$ distance from the origin. Then note that
$$\mathbb{P}_0(\nu_r \geq nM) = \sum_{x \in B_r}\mathbb{P}_0(\nu_r \geq nM|S_{(n-1)M} = x)\mathbb{P}_0(S_{(n-1)M} = x, \nu_r \geq (n-1)M).$$
We can get rid of the left factor by using our event and some relabelling:
$$\mathbb{P}_0(\nu_r \geq nM|S_{(n-1)M} = x) = \mathbb{P}_x(\nu_r \geq M) \leq \mathbb{P}_x(A^C) = \mathbb{P}_0(A^C).$$
We end up with
$$\mathbb{P}_0(\nu_r \geq nM) \leq \mathbb{P}_0(A^C)\mathbb{P}_0(\nu_r \geq (n-1)M)$$
by summing over $x \in B_r$ for the values of $S_{(n-1)M}$.

Comment: Why would A have positive probability  for anything else than for $x_0 =0$? The statement of the problem says the random walker starts at the origin, while your event A has it starting at any point

Comment: Notice that the notation in the problem is that $S_n$ represents the position at time n. But I think you are using $X_n$ for that. So I wonder also if in your suggestion that $\{\nu_r \le n\}=\cup_{j=1}^n\{X_j|^2>r\}$ you meant that $X_j $ is the position at time $j$, instead of the step taken at time $j$

Comment: Yes, I meant to say $S_n$, thanks for the catch. $A$ has positive probability because it's just asking if the unstopped random walk takes $M$ steps to the right.

Comment: This is overcomplicated in my opinion. Finiteness of $E[\tau]$ should follow from:
$$E[\tau]=\lim_{n \to \infty}E[D^2_{\tau\wedge n}]\leq (r+1)^2$$

Comment: Yea this is the better way of doing it, thanks.

Comment: @Snoop . Could you elaborate on how to get those relations?

Comment: Looks like I could also use the lemma in the picture I just added, provided I can identified N,$\epsilon$ and the probability inequality given as assumption in the context of the problem.

Comment: @some_math_guy use OST and obtain $0=E[D_{\nu_r\wedge n}^2-(\nu_r\wedge n)]$. Then note by monotone convergence $E[(\nu_r\wedge n)]\to E[\nu_r]$.

Comment: @Snoop. Got it thank you, Any idea how can I prove that $\{\nu_r \le n\}=\cup_{j=1}^n\{|S_j|^2>r\}$? Double inclusion of course but I don't see the relationship

Comment: @some_math_guy when proving equality of sets, proceed by showing $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$: argue by choosing $\omega$ in either side, and prove it's in the other.